# Combine columns from all child records into one column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following Parent-Child tables:

PARENT TABLE

```
PARENT_ID | COL_A 

1         |  "DOG"
2         |  "CAT"
3         |  "FROG"
```

CHILD TABLE

```
CHILD_ID  | PARENT_ID | COL_B   | COL_C
 
1         |  1        | "JOE"   | "DOE"
2         |  2        | "BOB"   | "BOBSON"
3         |  2        | "MARY"  | "DOETTE"
4         |  3        | "KEVIN" | "KEVINSON"
5         |  3        | "TOM"   | "TOMSON"
6         |  3        | "VIC"   | "VICSON"
```

I want to now combine all the child rows into a single row by concatating the columns in a custom way so that it will produce nice html.

The desired output is as such:

```
PARENT_ID | COL_A    | CUSTOM_COL

1         |  "DOG"   | <H1>JOE DOE</H1>
2         |  "CAT"   | <H1>BOB BOBSON, MARY DOETTE</H1>
3         |  "FROG"  | <H1>KEVIN KEVINSON, TOM TOMSON, VIC VICSON</H1>
```

Essentially what I am trying to do is to combine all the children row columns in a way where I can customize the output. In this case, I need the column to be an html string.

I am able to join the tables such as

```
SELECT 
p.*,c.*
FROM
PARENT_TABLE p
LEFT JOIN
CHILD_TABLE c
ON p.PARENT_ID = c.PARENT_ID
```

but this produces rows that aren't combined. How can I combine all the children rows into one?

Comment: Generating html would rather be relegated elsewhere than SQL.

Comment: @Tarik - you couldn't be more wrong, and I don't mean the confusion between html and xml. Oracle has had exceptionally deep and efficient support for xml for a very long time. It's OK not to know that - just leave it to people who work with Oracle all the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to use a [`listagg`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030)

```
SELECT p.parent_id,
       p.col_a,
       '<h1>' ||
         listagg(c.col_b || ' ' || c.col_c) 
           within group( order by c.child_id ) ||
         '</h1>' agg_column
  FROM PARENT_TABLE p
       LEFT JOIN CHILD_TABLE c
         ON p.PARENT_ID = c.PARENT_ID
 GROUP BY p.parent_id,
          p.col_a
```

Answer (score 1):

Join with `listagg`; sample data till line #10; query begins at line #11.

```
SQL> with
  2  parent (parent_id, col_a) as
  3    (select 1, 'Dog' from dual union all
  4     select 2, 'Cat' from dual
  5    ),
  6  child (child_id, parent_Id, col_b, col_c) as
  7    (select 1, 1, 'Joe', 'Doe'     from dual union all
  8     select 2, 2, 'Bob', 'Bobson'  from dual union all
  9     select 3, 2, 'Mary', 'Doette' from dual
 10    )
 11  select p.parent_id, p.col_a,
 12    '<H1>' ||
 13    listagg(c.col_b ||' '|| c.col_c, ', ') within group (order by null)  ||
 14    '</H1>' custom_col
 15  from parent p join child c on c.parent_id = p.parent_id
 16  group by p.parent_Id, p.col_a;

 PARENT_ID COL CUSTOM_COL
---------- --- ----------------------------------------
         1 Dog <H1>Joe Doe</H1>
         2 Cat <H1>Bob Bobson, Mary Doette</H1>

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are generating xml elements, you should use xml functions. In the query below I use `xmlserialize` to generate the strings exactly as you show them, but in your real-life application you may only need to generate the `xmlelements` (without calling `xmlserialize` on the result).

Assuming the tables are called `parent` and `child`, with the columns you showed, the query and output look like this:

```
select parent_id, col_a,
       xmlserialize(document xmlelement("HI", hi_list)) as custom_col
from   (
         select parent_id, 
                listagg(col_b || ' ' || col_c, ', ') 
                        within group (order by child_id) as hi_list
         from   child
         group  by parent_id
       )
       full outer join parent using (parent_id)
;

PARENT_ID COL_A CUSTOM_COL
--------- ----- -----------------------------------------------
        1 DOG   <HI>JOE DOE</HI>                
        2 CAT   <HI>BOB BOBSON, MARY DOETTE</HI>
        3 FROG  <HI>KEVIN KEVINSON, TOM TOMSON, VIC VICSON</HI>
```

I used a full outer join, just in case there are unmatched id's in either table. You can change to your left outer join (it would be right outer join in my query).